# Add Pagination/Toolbar using array of product ID's

Tags: pagination, toolbar

I have a custom view that uses a range of conditional statements on a collection to narrow down a specific set of product ids. I then need to be able to display these with the pagination and toolbar present

```
// create product collection
$_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory();  
$collection = $_category->getProductCollection();
Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->prepareProductCollection($collection);

//  create empty array for product id's
$ids = array();

// if and else conditions on collection for each
foreach($collection as $_product){
    $cats = $_product->getCategoryIds();
    if (condition 1 == ...){
        if (condition 2 == ...){
        } 
        else if (condition 3 == ...) {
        }
    } 
}

// end up with final array of product ids
$ids
```

How can i take these product ids and add the toolbar and pagination to it (like a normal view?) I've simplified the above code so it's clearer as I had a lot of irrelevant code in there so hopefully it makes sense

Answer (score 1):

The pagination does not work once the collection is loaded.
You should translate your condition to sql statements and you will be able to use the standard pagination.